# XOR constraint in class diagram

Tags: class-diagram, astah

How can I create a XOR constraint between two relationships in a class diagram using Astah Community Edition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Astah does not support {xor} constraint as a model. However, you can use Note and Note Anchor to show it as follows:

(1) Create a note and input "{xor}" in it.

(2) Add note anchors between a note and associations.

Please refer to the post below.
http://astah-users.change-vision.com/en/modules/xhnewbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=3236